# Why the tag statement is getting displayed multiple times for my Log

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-log

I am using a log statement for a click listener to show the Strings in a array list. And as per the official documentation, the "tag" parameter in Log.i(tag, message) is used to identify the source of a log message. It usually identifies the class or activity where the log call occurs.Below is the code to log the strings of array list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Response.size(); i++){
      Log.i("Resulted String", Response.get(i));
  }
```

In the logcat, the strings in arraylist have been displayed. but, for the first run tag statement is displayed before all the strings. and second run the tag is displaying 2/3 times and so on.below is the output which i got for the first run of the code.

> **Resulted String:** StatusOK
>       Amount2500.00score983
>       CAR25.00score773
>       LAR2200.00score780
>       Codeline.125000024._81922_767,_1127score993
>       PayeeNameGscore23
>       DateMay5,2018score925
>       CheckNumber1127score1000

And the tag is displaying as follows for the next runs.

> **Resulted String:** StatusOK
>       Amount2500.00score983
>       CAR25.00score773
>       LAR2200.00score780
>       Codeline.125000024._81922_767,_1127score993
>       PayeeNameGscore23
>   **Resulted String:** DateMay5,2018score925
>       CheckNumber1127score1000
>   **Resulted String:** StatusOK
>       Amount2500.00score983
>       CAR25.00score773
>   **Resulted String:** LAR2200.00score780
>       Codeline.125000024._81922_767,_1127score993
>       PayeeNameGscore23
>       DateMay5,2018score925
>       CheckNumber1127score1000

My question is why this tag statement not getting displayed along with each string and why displaying only with couple of strings and on which basis.

Please someone give the clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Concatenate into `StringBuffer` then `log` it after the loop

Comment: plz share `getSplittedResult` code.

Comment: Print `Response.size` to validate the list size

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuilder` as follows to achieve your intended output:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < Response.size(); i++){
     stringBuilder.append(Response.get(i));
}
Log.i("Resulted String", stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: I need to get the result as separated strings mentioned in query, so i used arraylist<Strings> for that. And with this solution i can generate a single string which should be changed to Arraylist<Strings> again.

Comment: @jellybean  `And with this solution i can generate a single string which i should be changed to Arraylist<Strings> again` what do you mean? You mean you want to keep the strings separate and print in different line?